# Character to be first in sort

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects like this:

```
var myArray = [{name: 'John', sortItem: 'abra'}, {name: 'Doe', sortItem: 'cadabra'}]
```

Some given constrains:

1. these items are dynamic - both "name" and "sortItem" properties;
2. there's a good reason for displaying the name but sorting by another field;
3. this array is coming from the server thus has to be easily JSON stringify-able.

Then I sort it with `sortBy(myArray, 'sortItem')` (`sortBy` is from [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs#sortBy)).

Now I want to add a default option and I want to make sure it's always the first option after sorting. So I tried some options:

1. `var myList = ['a', 'A', 0]; _.sortBy(myList)` results in `["A", "a", 0]`
2. `var myList = ['a', 'A', '_']; _.sortBy(myList)` results in `["A", "_", "a"]`
3. `var myList = ['a', 'A', '.']; _.sortBy(myList)` results in `[".", "A", "a"]`
4. `var myList = ['a', 'A', '']; _.sortBy(myList)` results in `["", "A", "a"]`

---

Seems that my best bet for now is to add `{name: 'Default', sodtItem: ''}` but is there another character/value that will ensure me that my default item is first?

## Edit

The question is not how to build a sort function; but instead, what character has the lowest "value" in Javascript?

In other words, if you take a list of all possible characters (those that pass jsonification) and sort them - what would be the first character?

Comment: Sort functions will produces unexpected results with the same string. Use it carefully.

Comment: Can you sort first and *then* insert the default item?

Comment: what is the character to sort first?

Comment: Or create your own sort function and check if the sodItem is not there than place in front.

Comment: Sorry for not stating the question clear. I've added an edit to the question above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add another sorting field, which would determine the main order, and the "sortItem" will be your secondary sort.

So your sorting looks like:

```
_.sortBy(myArray, ['default', 'sortItem'])
```

And your array looks like:

```
var myArray = [
    {name: 'John', sortItem: 'abra'}, 
    {name: 'Doe', sortItem: 'cadabra'}, 
    {name: 'This is the default', sortItem: 'zzzzz', default: true}
];
```

Comment: That's a valid option, but I'd wait to see if there's a more straightforward answer. If not, I'll mark this as an answer.